# WINAPI how to wait until all threads finish?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I want to simulate Java's behavior of waiting until all threads in the process finish before the main exits in C/Windows API.

The behavior I want to simulate is one of the sample code below(it spams `[second thread] active threads: 2.`, and does not terminate even when main returns):

```java
public final class Test1
{
    // | prints current thread count and queues the next iteration.
    static void step() {
        System.out.println (
            "[second thread] active threads: " + 
            Thread.activeCount() +
            "."
        );   
        new Thread(() -> step()).start();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // | queue the first iteration.
        new Thread(() -> step()).start();      
    }
}
```

My initial idea was to completely take over the main of my program, and instead do all the work in another function, eg `main2` and if it finishes early, I will wait until the rest of the threads finish.

My problem is that my main has no idea what other threads exist, and even if it did know what other threads existed, after they all finish, it is still possible that they have spawned more threads, that we are again not aware of.

My approach to tackle this looks something as follows:

`main.c` would contain the actual main, and the actual main logic would be moved out to `main2`(or something with a better name). `main` would potentially resort to using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` to discover threads that do not match its own [GetThreadId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadid) and wait for them(potentially aggregating existing threads to avoid only fetching one existing thread at a time, to take advantage of `WaitForMultipleObjects`).

```cpp
/**
 * @file main.c
 */
#include <Windows.h>

// | This function will can start threads without worrying about them
// |     ending as soon as it finishes.
extern int main2(int argc, char **argv);

// | NOT IMPLEMENTED: I have no idea if such a service exists, but it can probably be
// |     implemented using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.
// | If it did exist, it would return a single thread from the process 
// |     not matching the current thread id.
extern HANDLE WINAPI SorceryToDiscoverASingleOtherThreadThatExists();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int returnValue;
    
    // | main2 will do the actual main's work.
    returnValue = main2(argc, argv);
    
    // | Do not finish before other threads finish.    
    for (;;) {
        HANDLE hThread;
        
        // | Find a single thread handle whose thread id is 
        // |     not the same as the current thread's.
        hThread = SorceryToDiscoverASingleOtherThreadThatExists();        
        
        // | If there are no more threads, 
        // |     we can finally break out of this infinite loop.
        if (hThread == 0) {
            break;
        }
        
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And main2.c which would behave as our java program would:

```cpp
/**
 * @file main2.c
 */
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD CALLBACK ThreadProc0001(LPVOID unused) {
    puts("Hello, World!");
    CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc0001, 0, 0, 0);
    
    return 0;
}

int main2(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc0001, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

With proof of concept to make sure the above code works(deep_thread_nesting.c):

```cpp
/**
 * @file deep_thread_nesting.c
 */
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD CALLBACK ThreadProc0001(LPVOID unused) {
    puts("Hello, World!");
    CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc0001, 0, 0, 0);
    
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc0001, 0, 0, 0);
    
    // | Do not exit until user presses ctrl c.
    for (;;) {
        // | Reduce strain on the CPU from the infinite loop.
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I feel forced to use one of three incredibly ugly solutions:

The first involving the mystical `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` function as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-thread-list) tutorial describes, in order to fetch one(or potentially be optimized further to return more than one thread that does not match our active thread id) thread handle(s) that we can use to wait on.

The second involving keeping a global registry of all the handles and having each thread lock the world, add the handle to the registry, remove its own handle, and unlock the world, possibly writing my own CreateThread wrapper that takes care of this for me.

The third being a rough idea, as I have no idea if this even works the way I think it does, hooking the `CreateThread` function to make all threads implement the second solution.

**Question**

Is there a way to make C or Windows API wait for all my threads to finish
before terminating the program without effectively writing my own runtime?

Comment: @beothunder The main does not know the handles of the threads it wants to wait for. I already considered using `WaitForMultipleObjects`, which is why I mentioned an optimization to discover multiple thread `HANDLE`s at once(rather than the current one only discovering one at a time).

Comment: You are not accounting for the fact that the OS may also create threads in your process for its own purposes. So using a loop on `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` until the thread count drops to 1 (the one running `main()`) is not very realistic. Your 2nd idea is the way to go. Keep track of the threads you explicitly create yourself, and then wait on just those threads. That is what Java does behind the scenes. Wrap your thread logic inside a reusable interface that adds itself to a list when started, and removes itself from the list when finished, then you can iterate that list whenever needed.

Comment: you must not wait for all threads exit. only if you create thread yourself and need by your task logic wait for it - you wait. in other case not need wait

Comment: Based on the comments, it appears the best solution would be my own domain specific `Thread`/service implementation/solution #2, that needs to add itself when it start and remove itself when it finishes, and main can block on my application's global thread blocking registry, likely using a lock. I am guessing there might also be a possibility to utilize atexit somewhere along the way to avoid having the unintuitive main2-main split, which I am guessing other thread creators(outside main program flow) who want to wait on them would handle waiting themselves.

Comment: It appears that the most frustrating part would be intercepting when the thread returns(to remove its handle out of the global thread handle list), as I would need to either wrap CreateThread call to produce an additional argument for  the actual thread callback, so that the CreateThread wrapper would be able to take care of removing the thread from the global thread list, or I would need to create a 2nd "weak" thread for each thread I create whose only job is to wait for the first thread to finish for it to remove that thread's id out of the global thread list.

Comment: Whan I worked on an application that created a lot of threads, my solution was to create a waiter thread once per `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`

Comment: Actually, can't you just count the number of created threads, and increment a counter every time a thread returns? Then `WaitOnAddress` in main? @Dmitry

Comment: @beothunder First of all I am not sure simply counting it works since I now realize there might be "weak" threads that exist but take care of their own destruction if they care enough to do so. Also I now realize that it isn't straightforward to asynchronously detect when a thread returns(as the code has nobody to wait for anything synchronously, it just does its thing and leaves). Also I don't want my thread users to have to deal with counting anything themselves, they just want to do  their own thing.

Comment: Yeah, I meant counting instead of "removing the thread from the global thread list", not instead of "weak" threads.

Comment: Hold up... "thread users"? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: @beothunder anything that calls CreateThread is a thread user. They want the threads to pretend to behave like normal threads, without having to do anything extra.

Comment: @beothunder I am beginning to see what you mean. After a bunch of bashing my head against this, I am not sure if there is any reason for me to keep a list of thread handles. In the end, main seems better off sleeping a bit than calling WaitForMultipleObjects because I have a feeling realloc for adding/removing thread handles(even if there is only a single one) invalidates the WaitForMultipleObjects(or even WaitForSingleObject) as the thread list changes way too often. It seems easier to just check if the thread count is > 0 and if so go back to sleep, loop.

Comment: The C Language Specification mandates that returning from `main` must have the effect of terminating the program. To change that behavior you will have to provide your own language runtime. The system provides you with callbacks for thread creation/termination already: [`DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain). This works regardless of how client code creates threads. There is no requirement to go through a thread creation routine you would provide.

Comment: I have made my quesiton more explicit and removed distracting "not actually an answer", as it was not actually an answer and would better be suited for codereview.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but, as mentioned by IInspectable, `ExitProcess` is called by the CRT. So getting rid of the CRT the behaviour that you are looking for is restored.

Compile with `/NODEFAULTLIB`, include libraries using the command line and not `#pragma comment(lib, ...)`.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI other_thread(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if ((hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ||
        (!hOut))
    {
        if (IsDebuggerPresent()) __debugbreak();
        return -1;
    }

    constexpr char string[] = "I am writing!\r\n";
    for (;;)
    {
        WriteFile(hOut, string, sizeof(string), 0, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}

int mainCRTStartup()
{
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, other_thread, 0, 0, 0);

    return 1;
}
```

The `other_thread` continues writing, even after the `mainCRTStartup` exits.

Comment: The CRT does *a lot* more than terminating the process when the primary thread exits. You're losing all of that, such as a properly initialized floating point environment, 64-bit integer support, or initialization of objects with static storage duration.

Comment: That's why it is "Not really an answer".

Answer (score -1):

An answer that is closer to what the OP intended:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "synchronization.lib")

// the program will not (usually) exit, until this counter is at 0
long long deployed_threads_counter;

// we need a place to store the user's function pointer,
// as the lpStartAddress parameter of CreateThread is already used
struct ThreadParameters
{
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE  lpStartAddress;
    LPVOID                  lpParameter;
};

// a wrapper around the user provided LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE
DWORD WINAPI my_thread_start(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    // dereferenced! my_create_thread can now exit
    ThreadParameters thread_parameters = *(ThreadParameters*)lpThreadParameter;
    WakeByAddressSingle(lpThreadParameter);
    // actually do the work
    BOOL result = thread_parameters.lpStartAddress(thread_parameters.lpParameter);
    // signal that the thread has finished executing
    InterlockedDecrement64(&deployed_threads_counter);
    WakeByAddressSingle(&deployed_threads_counter);
    return result;
}

// CreateThread substitude incurs the desired behaviour
HANDLE my_create_thread(
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   lpThreadAttributes,
    SIZE_T                  dwStackSize,
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE  lpStartAddress,
    LPVOID                  lpParameter,
    DWORD                   dwCreationFlags,
    LPDWORD                 lpThreadId)
{
    InterlockedIncrement64(&deployed_threads_counter);
    ThreadParameters thread_parameters =
    {
        lpStartAddress,
        lpParameter,
    };
    // call my_thread_start instead, so that the thread exit is signaled
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
        lpThreadAttributes,
        dwStackSize,
        my_thread_start,
        &thread_parameters,
        dwCreationFlags,
        lpThreadId);
    // do not destroy thread_parameters, until my_thread_start has finished using them
    WaitOnAddress(&thread_parameters, &lpStartAddress, sizeof(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE), INFINITE);
    return hThread;
}

// optionally set this behaviour to be the default
#define CreateThread my_create_thread

int use_this_main();
int main()
{
    // execute user code
    int result = use_this_main();
    // wait for all threads to finish
    while (auto temp = deployed_threads_counter)
    {
        WaitOnAddress(&deployed_threads_counter, &temp, sizeof(temp), INFINITE);
    }
    // fallthrough return
    return result;
}

int use_this_main()
{
    // your code here...

    return 0;
}
```

*Currently there is actually a race condition, if `InterlockedIncrement64` is called after the `main`'s `WaitOnAddress`. This can be prevented, with something like a double gate system, but the answer is already complicated enough.*

Comment: As noted in the last comment of the question, the question is exclusively about whether it can be done without creating my own runtime. That said, I don't see a reason to make the thread creation wrapper block itself until the thread finishes copying the arguments(using an expensive system API). Using dynamic memory and having a narrow contract that the proc wrapper cleans up after itself avoids needing to worry about the callback trying to copy arguments on expired stack of the creation wrapper.  The second wait eliminates the benefits of threading altogether as it blocks on the thread

Comment: `The second wake eliminates the benefits of Threading altogether as the CreateThread wrapper blocks.` WDYM? It is not `WainOnAddress`, it is `Wake`. As in: if there are any threads waiting on that address, one of them will be resumed.

Comment: The argument passing can be done however you want. If you care, measure the performance of different approaches.

Comment: My bad, I thought the wait for waiting for `deployed_threads_counter` but it was actually waiting for `thread_parameters`. If I understood correctly, the creation wrapper returns as soon as the parameters are copied. The main wakes up each time a single thread is removed. It makes sense(It might still be more expensive to wait/wake than to allocate/free, but that's not really an issue for a proof of concept, and I could also be wrong on that too depending on malloc/free implementation).

Comment: About the `without creating my own runtime` thing. Well, this isn't much of a runtime, it's 2.5 functions :D    You have to do *something* to reproduce this behaviour.    I still am not quite sure about the use case of any of this. Something like fire and forget approach? It seems to me that most of the time there is a natural place to put a `WaitForX` call.

Comment: One use case is creating my own naive window objects(C++ or COM style, doesn't matter) that i can attach event callbacks to in the "main", and after "main" exits the window still exists. Or just move a boring single window to a separate thread independant of main.

Comment: `DuplicateHandle` to the main thread, store it somewhere (so you can terminate it, when you want to exit the program), and call `SuspendThread(GetCurrentThread())` at the end of `main`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246920/discussion-between-dmitry-and-beothunder).

Comment: [Why you should never suspend a thread](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031209-00/?p=41573).

Comment: @IInspectable Literally irrelevant. More like: you should never suspend a thread, if you have no idea what it does. In this case the calling thread would be suspended.

Comment: It is my understanding that a thread can continue executing code after a successful call to `SuspendThread(GetCurrentThread())`. While you can, in theory, arrange for things to work out, keeping it that way over time is near impossible. It's needless complexity, too. Since this scheme requires external code to trigger thread termination, you might as well just create a synchronization primitive and signal that instead.

Comment: @IInspectable 1. It really shouldn't. Even if this function is specifically designed for debuggers, you need to guarantee in that case, that target thread stopped executing, so that something like `GetThreadContext` or reading process memory will always work. These extranious calls do not go throgh the scheduler (if that's what you're thinking).  2. Yes, it is needless complexity. It was just an idea.